# Convert Multiple Columns to Relative Frequency by Group in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df with some grouping variables and several other numeric variables with the same prefix.

```
have <-
  data.frame(
    group = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10)),
    x1 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
    x3 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE)
  )
```

The number and name of these numeric variables will change, but they will always have `x` prefix.

I need to convert them to relative frequency by group. I can do this manually like this:

```
want <-
  have %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(x1_freq = x1 / sum(x1),
         x2_freq = x2 / sum(x2),
         x3_freq = x3 / sum(x3)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

But then the next time when there are 5, or 10, or 50 of these `x` variables, this isn't ideal...how can I do this for all variables starting with `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `across()` and `starts_with()`!

```
library(tidyverse)

my.freq = function(x){
  #just calculating the frequency. I prefer to make my functions outside of chains
  x / sum(x)
}

ideal <-
  have %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("x"),
                .fns = my.freq,
                .names = "{.col}_freq"
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
```